# Any robust plugins with Markdown Extra support?

Tags: plugins, filter

I've tried [@monooso](https://twitter.com/monooso)’s [Smartdown](https://github.com/monooso/smartdown.craft-plugin) plugin but can’t get it to run on my local install of Craft 2.5 under PHP 5.6.10.

I have content that parses fine as regular Markdown but just fails totally with the **smartdown** filter applied. I've read somewhere that Smartdown is a work in progress. (I'll ask Stephen about it.)

I note with interest a recent release from Pixel & Tonic for a Parsedown plugin: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Parsedown.

But not yet found a plugin that executes either Markdown Extra or [Parsedown Extra](http://parsedown.org/extra/) on regular Plaintext fields.

Comment: As a sidebar, the Parsedown plugin is noticeably faster :)

Comment: Selvin Ortiz' [Doxter plugin](https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.doxter) has Parsedown Extra support. I haven't tested it myself or know if it can be used w/ Plaintext Fields, which is why I'm writing this comment and not adding an answer.

Comment: Thanks, Mats. I’m aware of Doxter but haven’t got my head round it entirely yet. I need to do so!

Comment: I released Smartdown 2 a few days back (warning: it contains breaking changes, so check the README). If that doesn't work for you, feel free to open an issue on the repo with some details of the problem.